# retrieve object in array with condition mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

i have a `MONGODB` database to places like Restaurant Or Cafe and each place have an `Array Of Object` with name TABLES and each object has `Number of table, and Array of booking Dates and details` user can book any table by date and time so i want to check available tables and return the table that not booked in this time that user wants to book..

HERE IS MY SCHEMA FOR TABLES ARRAY

```
tables: [
      {
        num: Number,
        isBooked: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        bookings: [
          {
            User: {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "Users",
            },
            Name: {
              type: String,
            },
            Date: {
              type: String,
            },
            Time: {
              type: String,
            },
            Note: {
              type: String,
            },
            numOfPersons: {
              type: Number,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

and if user want to book a table at ***20/8/2021 , 4:00PM*** we should check available table for this user at this time requested, we should check on tables and return available table the we push the booking information into it..

i tried some query but always return the whole place not just available table..

```
    const stringDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
    const placeId = req.body.placeId;

    const availableTable = await Places.findOne({
      _id: placeId,
      "tables[0].bookings": {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: { $and: [{ Date: stringDate }, { Time: time }] },
        },
      },
    });
    
    availableTable.isBooked = true;
    availableTable.bookings.push({
      Name: name,
      Time: time,
      Date: stringDate,
      numOfPersons: parseInt(personsNumber),
      Note: note,
      User: userId,
    });
   await availableTable.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for simplicity, you should have a separate collection for tables with the restaurant/cafe id in it. That way you can easily do CRUD operations on tables and it would the best approach to handle it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).